# Redirect - Failed to load source for: website

Tags: php, html, header, firebug

I need a bit of support on this error, I have Google'd it and cant seem to find anything that solves my issue.

I get this error in Firebug, when I try to redirect from my index.php page to another page on the same server. It also keeps refreshing (30+ times) and fails to fully load.

```
Failed to load source for: https://www.example.com/
```

In the index page:

```
<?php

header('Location:index2.php');
exit;
?>
```

And the index2.php i have no PHP.

.htaccess :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are you rewriting your urls using for example an `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Hi @swapnesh Yes i am using SSL. I think i am rewriting my url? I have also pasted my .htaccess file above.

Comment: All pages on your site are redirecting forever.

Comment: Hi @CodeCaster sorry i dont follow ya.. is there an error in my RewriteRules?

Comment: Yes. Take a look with a tool like Fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

Is that an include on the pages? Try adding

```
header('HTTP/1.0 200 OK');
```

above your location.

Comment: Hi @Dave, no i do not have any includes. i have tried your 200 OK.. but sadly it doesn't solve. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

It was down to a simple iframe that was located on the page and redirecting the header back to the main index page. Was removed and the issue was resolved.

Thanks for all your help guys